# Login SAP, with Powershell using SAP Connector for Microsoft .NET

Tags: .net, powershell, sap-erp, sap-gui

I try to login into a SAP system using the interface SAP Connector for Microsoft .NET. It worked for me to login with another method, without SAP Connector, with `sapshcut`, code below:

```
  #-Start the SAP GUI-----------------------------------------

    $SID = "t30.lan"

    $SAPGUI = $SAPGUIPath + "sapgui.exe"
    & $SAPGUI $SID $InstanceNo    
    & $SAPGUIPath\sapshcut.exe -maxgui  -system=t30 -client=110 -user=test -pw=test01 -language=DE
```

Now I imported the SAP Connector for Microsoft .NET. I want to set a connection with a code example like this:

```
  #-Function Get-Destination--------------------------------------------
  Function Get-Destination {

    #-Connection parameters---------------------------------------------
    $cfgParams = New-Object SAP.Middleware.Connector.RfcConfigParameters
    $cfgParams.Add("NAME", "Testsystem")
    $cfgParams.Add("ASHOST", "t30.lan")
    $cfgParams.Add("SYSNR", "01")
    $cfgParams.Add("CLIENT", "110")
    $cfgParams.Add("USER", "test")
    $cfgParams.Add("PASSWD", "test01")

    Return [SAP.Middleware.Connector.RfcDestinationManager]::GetDestination($cfgParams)

  }
```

It's not working. I think I set the parameters wrong, but I don't find help in the internet. I'm getting a log like that, and I think it didn't work, because of **`OnCharacterConversationError : 1`**. My Console Log looks like this:

```
IsShutDown                      : False
Repository                      : 
SystemAttributes                : 
TraceLevel                      : 0
User                            : test
AliasUser                       : 
Client                          : 110
SystemNumber                    : 01
SystemID                        : 
Language                        : 
AppServerHost                   : t30.lan
AppServerService                : 
MessageServerHost               : 
MessageServerService            : 
LogonGroup                      : 
SAPRouter                       : 
Codepage                        : 
PartnerCharSize                 : 
UseSAPCodepages                 : 
UseSymbolicNames                : 0
LogonCheck                      : 1
SncMode                         : 
SncMyName                       : 
SncPartnerName                  : 
SncLibraryPath                  : 
SncQOP                          : 8
SncSSO                          : 1
UseSAPGui                       : 0
AbapDebug                       : 0
NoCompression                   : 0
NoBasXml                        : 0
Delta                           : 1
OnCharacterConversionError      : 1
CharacterFaultIndicatorToken    : #
PoolSize                        : 10
PeakConnectionsLimit            : 10
MaxPoolSize                     : 10
PoolIdleTimeout                 : 3600
IdleTimeout                     : 600
ConnectionIdleTimeout           : 600
RepositoryConnectionIdleTimeout : 600
IdleCheckTime                   : 600
MaxPoolWaitTime                 : 
Monitor                         : SAP.Middleware.Connector.RfcDestinationMonitor
```

Comment: not sure that is an error. When you have the rfc destination, you can use the method Ping() of the destination to check whether you can connect.

Comment: Can you give some more details on what exactly you are trying to achieve? If you want to log on in dialog, you need to go via SAPgui / SAPgui automation, if you want to call RFC functions you need to use SAP Connector. Another possibility is providing a service in SAP and use Invoke-WebRequest or Invoke-RestMethod to call it from PowerShell.

Comment: Hello @ThomasErdösi i try to display delivery notes, with a script that auto login into my sap. I got a  working vbs script that works with RFC, it is login automaticly into sap, and showing those delivery bills, but i have to translate it into powershell. but im not sure how to do

Comment: Can you provide the essential parts of the vbs script you want to convert?

Answer (score 0):

```
'load rfc
Set rfc = sap.Add("Z_GET_ARCHIVE_FILE_URL")

'fill import parameter
rfc.Exports("SAP_OBJECT") = "x45f"
rfc.Exports("OBJECT_ID") = purchase_order
rfc.Exports("ARCHIV_TAB") = "tt520"
rfc.Exports("ARCHIV_ID") = "x6"
rfc.Exports("AR_OBJECT") = "zmst07"
    
'execute 
If Not rfc.Call Then
    'if fails error
    If rfc.Exception = "INVALID_ARCHIVE_TABLE" Then
        MsgBox "infalid (" & rfc.Exception & ").", vbCritical, "Error"
    ElseIf rfc.Exception = "NO_DOCUMENT_FOUND" Then
        MsgBox "cant find object (" & rfc.Exception & ").", vbCritical, "Error"
    ElseIf rfc.Exception = "ERROR_IN_URL_READING" Then
        MsgBox "URL not read (" & rfc.Exception & ").", vbCritical, "Error"
    Else
        MsgBox "SAP Fehler: " & rfc.Exception, vbCritical, "Error"
    End If
    sap.Connection.Logoff
    Wscript.Quit
End If

'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------'
'read data of rfc 
Set it_data = rfc.Tables("T_URLS")
sap.Connection.Logoff

If it_data.Rows.Count > 0 Then
    For i = 1 To it_data.Rows.Count Step 1
        'open browser
        Set objIEBrowser = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
        objIEBrowser.Visible = True
        objIEBrowser.Navigate2 it_data.Value(i, "LINE") & "" 'needed
        Do While objIEBrowser.Busy
            'Warten
        Loop
    Next
    'empty stack
    it_data.FreeTable
Else
    MsgBox "object not found.", vbCritical, "Error"
End If
```

Comment: @ThomasErdösi, here is the code i want to transfer into powershell